# JQuery function return another function

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

is this possible? I got this 2 function here.

1. function `item_details()` - this function will return all values from the grid using for loop.

```js
function item_details(){
  /* to get all value from grid */

  var gridDataArray_1 = $('#itemGrid').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.data()
  var columnDataVector_1 = [];

  'itemLength: ' + gridDataArray_1.length;

  for ( var i=0; i < gridDataArray_1.length; i++ ) {
    'itemID_'+ i + ": " + gridDataArray_1[i]['itemID'];
    'itemQty_'+ i + ": " + gridDataArray_1[i]['itemQuantity']
    'itemPrice_'+ i + ": " + gridDataArray_1[i]['itemPrice']                 
  };
}
```

2. function `data()` - this function will be call inside ajax return data

```js
function data(){
    return { 
        method: "editRecipe",
        this_propertyID : $('#thisPropertyID').val(),
    }
}
```

It is possible to combine the values from `item_function()` with the `data()` function? So when I call data() function it will return like this?

```js
method: editRecipe
this_propertyID: 1
itemLength: 2
itemID_0: LA1
itemQty_0: 1
itemPrice_0: 10000
itemID_1: LA8
itemQty_1: 1
itemPrice_1: 65
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var combinedData = [];

var item_details =  item_details();
var data = data();

combinedData .push(item_details);
combinedData .push(data);
```

If you want to combine it in data() function, then

```
function data(){
    var combinedData = [];
    var data = { 
        method: "editRecipe",
        this_propertyID : $('#thisPropertyID').val()
        }
    var item_details =  item_details();

    combinedData.push(item_details);
    combinedData.push(data);
    return combinedData;
}
```

Comment: nah. it won't work in data() function. should be outside of it. If you want to combine datas in data() function, then declare a variable which has return value of data() function.